# Using Poetry virtual environment and creating a venv in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, python-venv

It might be a silly question but I am wondering when setting up a poetry environment in PyCharm, do I still need to create a virtual environment using

```
python3 -m venv env
```

&

```
source env/bin/activate
```